# My code is throwing an TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

Tags: python, numpy

My code is throwing this error, but I have compared it to someone else's code and its basically the same thing, does anyone know why?

```
def solar_system(T, x_e, x_m, omega_e, omega_m):
    """Plot the trajectories of the earth and moon over the time interval [0,T]
    assuming the initial position of the earth is (x_e,0) and the initial
    position of the moon is (x_m,0).

    Parameters:
        T (int): The final time.
        x_e (float): The earth's initial x coordinate.
        x_m (float): The moon's initial x coordinate.
        omega_e (float): The earth's angular velocity.
        omega_m (float): The moon's angular velocity.
    """
    #raise NotImplementedError("Problem 2 Incomplete")
    
    t = np.linspace(0, T, 1000)
    earth_pos = []
    moon_pos = []
    for i in t:
        new_pos_e = [[math.cos(t*omega_e), -math.sin(t*omega_e)], [math.sin(t*omega_e), math.cos(t*omega_e)]] @ np.array([x_e,0]).T
        earth_pos.append(new_pos_e)
    earth_pos = np.array(earth_pos)
    plt.plot(earth_pos[:,0], earth_pos[:,1], 'b-', linewidth=3)
    
    for i in t:
        new_pos_m = [[math.cos(t*omega_m), -math.sin(t*omega_m)], [math.sin(t*omega_m), math.cos(t*omega_m)]] @ np.array([(x_m - x_e), 0]).T
        moon_pos.append(new_pos_m)
    moon_pos = np.array(moon_pos)
    plt.plot(moon_pos[:,0]+earth_pos[:,0], moon_pos[:,1]+earth_pos[:,1], "r-", linewidth=3)
        
    plt.axis("equal")
    plt.xlabel("x axis co-ordinates")
    plt.ylabel("y axis co-ordinates")
    plt.title("Earth and Moon Rotation")
    plt.legend("Earth", "Moon", loc="lower right")
    plt.show()
```

The error it is throwing is below:

```
TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

It says that the error is on this line:

```
new_pos_e = [[math.cos(t*omega_e), -math.sin(t*omega_e)], [math.sin(t*omega_e), math.cos(t*omega_e)]] @ np.array([x_e,0]).T
enter code here
```

I use this to run the function:

```
solar_system(3*np.pi/2, 10, 11, 1, 13)
```

Comment: Functions from `math` only operate on regular Python _numbers_ ("Python scalars" in the error message), not NumPy data structures. Looks like one of `t` and `omega_e` is not a number

Comment: Are you passing parameters to function exactly of that type that is mentioned in documentation in the beginning of function?

Comment: @ForceBru, that makes sense. Would I have to import anything to get it to work?

Comment: @Arty, yes I am. they gave us a test function and I copied it to make sure it's working and I got an error

Comment: @acme_2020 Can you also include in your post code that you're using to call the function? So that whole script can reproduce an error when run by us.

Comment: @Arty, I've included it

Comment: You write `for i in t`, but then use the array/list `t` in your computation instead of the `i`.

Answer (score 0):

Inside both loops you should use `i` instead of `t`, fixed full code below:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt, numpy as np, math

def solar_system(T, x_e, x_m, omega_e, omega_m):
    """Plot the trajectories of the earth and moon over the time interval [0,T]
    assuming the initial position of the earth is (x_e,0) and the initial
    position of the moon is (x_m,0).

    Parameters:
        T (int): The final time.
        x_e (float): The earth's initial x coordinate.
        x_m (float): The moon's initial x coordinate.
        omega_e (float): The earth's angular velocity.
        omega_m (float): The moon's angular velocity.
    """
    #raise NotImplementedError("Problem 2 Incomplete")

    t = np.linspace(0, T, 1000)
    earth_pos = []
    moon_pos = []
    for i in t:
        new_pos_e = [[math.cos(i * omega_e), -math.sin(i * omega_e)], [math.sin(i * omega_e), math.cos(i * omega_e)]] @ np.array([x_e, 0]).T
        earth_pos.append(new_pos_e)
    earth_pos = np.array(earth_pos)
    plt.plot(earth_pos[:,0], earth_pos[:,1], 'b-', linewidth=3)

    for i in t:
        new_pos_m = [[math.cos(i * omega_m), -math.sin(i * omega_m)], [math.sin(i * omega_m), math.cos(i * omega_m)]] @ np.array([(x_m - x_e), 0]).T
        moon_pos.append(new_pos_m)
    moon_pos = np.array(moon_pos)
    plt.plot(moon_pos[:,0]+earth_pos[:,0], moon_pos[:,1]+earth_pos[:,1], "r-", linewidth=3)
        
    plt.axis("equal")
    plt.xlabel("x axis co-ordinates")
    plt.ylabel("y axis co-ordinates")
    plt.title("Earth and Moon Rotation")
    plt.legend("Earth", "Moon", loc="lower right")
    plt.show()

solar_system(3*np.pi/2, 10, 11, 1, 13)
```